Выбор языка программирования для аналога FB2Reader
Хочу написать аналог программы FB2Reader. Который так же как и оригинал будет работать и на Android и на Windows. Из функций хочу добавить возможность встроенного vpn, а так же синхронизацию книг и документов на всех устройствах где одна учетная запись. И вот из потока сознания выше вопрос - подойдет ли для этих целей Python или другие языки программирования будут более правильны для решения данной задачи?

C# + MAUI......

Если планируете использовать наработки существующего FB2Reader-а, то C++ ,без вариантов. API только для него.  https://sdk.fbreader.org/

Если приложение планируется под мобильные устройства - Java/kotlin. На винде можно реализовать на любом языке.  На вашем месте я бы рассмотрел создание сайта, не нужно будет писать код на разные платформы и отпадает проблема с VPN

Из функций хочу добавить возможность встроенного vpn


зачем в читалке vpn?

Если хочется красивый дизайн на винду - js с Electron.
Upd: если нужен offline вариант - можно рассмотреть тг бот. Как я понял вам интересен Python - отличное решение для бота. Просто парсить описание книг и ссылки на скачивание (если такое присутствует) в бота.

vpn для доступа к сайтам заблокированным роскомпозором используя opds. Та же флибуста без впн не откроется и из самой читалки нельзя будет найти и скачать книгу. Идея с сайтом хороша, но без интернета получить к нему доступ будет невозможно, а значит отпадает такой вариант.
